# php compare glob vs file_exist in 4 folder and 10k files

Tags: php, glob, file-exists

I have 4 folder and each folder contain 10k images with random extension "gif" and "webp".I need to get full file location when search with filename.

please help me to get better performance.

My folder are folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4

example search with file_exists:

```
$filename= 'example12345';    
if(file_exists("folder1/".$filename.".webp")){
echo "folder1/".$filename.".webp";
}elseif(file_exists("folder2/".$filename.".webp")){
echo "folder2/".$filename.".webp";
}elseif(file_exists("folder3/".$filename.".webp")){
echo "folder3/".$filename.".webp";
}elseif(file_exists("folder4/".$filename.".webp")){
echo "folder4/".$filename.".webp";
}elseif(file_exists("folder1/".$filename.".gif")){
echo "folder1/".$filename.".gif";
}elseif(file_exists("folder2/".$filename.".gif")){
echo "folder2/".$filename.".gif";
}elseif(file_exists("folder3/".$filename.".gif")){
echo "folder3/".$filename.".gif";
}elseif(file_exists("folder4/".$filename.".gif")){
echo "folder4/".$filename.".gif";
}else{
echo "file not exists";
}
```

and example search with php glob:

```
$filename= 'example12345';
$search_files= glob("folder*/".$filename.".*");
echo $search_files[0] ?? "file not exists";
```

Note: im not use database to save index files.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a small number of folders and extensions involved, calling `file_exists` for each possible combination (as seen in your first code sample) will be faster than a `glob()` search, as `glob()` will list the full contents of each directory to check if each file matches.

However, this is a terrible design. Use a database, or at least organize the files in some more reasonable way.

Comment: can you give me ideas to organize the file but without database.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the question is relevant even today.

First of all, a database might not be any faster than checking for file existence directly. The file system is uses the same indexing data structures as any modern database. The file system don’t provide any good ways to perform advanced queries on those indexes, but making two `file_exists` checks would generally be quite a bit faster than first querying the database and then querying the file system.

You CAN do a few of things to help the situation:

1. If most files are “gif”, then check that first.
2. Consider skipping the “file_exists” call and jump directly to “fopen” and handle the error may help in some systems.
3. You can create a symlink for each file.